L1 error of kernel density estimator is also total variation distance empirical measure and true measure
In the following lecture notes called 'A Gentle Introduction to Empirical Process theory', they make the following statement in Example 3.25.

$\textbf{Example 3.25}$ (Kernel density estimation).Let $X_{1},\ldots,X_{n}$ be i.i.d. from a distribution $P$ on $\mathbb{R}$ ( the argument can be easily generalized to $\mathbb{R}^d$) with density $\phi .$ We want to estimate
$\phi$ nonparametrically using the kernel density estimator (KDE) $\hat{\phi}_n:\mathbb{R}\to[0,\infty)$ defined as
$$\hat{\phi}_{n}(x)=\frac{1}{nh_{n}}\sum_{i=1}^{n}K\left(\frac{x-X_{i}}{h_{n}}\right),\quad \text{for } x\in\mathbb{R},$$
where $h_{n}> 0$ $is$ the smoothing bandwidth and $K$ is a nonnegative kernel $( i. e.$, $K\geq 0$ and
$\int K(x)dx=1)$. The $L_1$-error of the estimator $\hat\phi_n$ is
$$Z\equiv f(X_1,\dots,X_n):=\int|\hat{\phi}_n(x)-\phi(x)|dx.$$
The random variable $Z$ not only provides a measure of the difference between $\hat{\phi}_n$ and $\phi$ but as $Z= 2\sup _{A}| P_{n}( A) - P( A) |$ (Exercise( HW1): Show this) where the supremum is over all Borel sets in $
\mathbb{R}$ and $P_{n}$ denotes the distribution corresponding to the KDE $\hat{\phi } _{n}$, $Z$ also captures the difference between $P_{n}$ and $P$ in the total variation distance.

Does anyone know to show Exercise HW1? That is, how to demonstrate that $$Z= \int|\hat{\phi}_n(x)-\phi(x)|dx = 2\sup _{A}| P_{n}( A) - P( A) |$$

It's a classical result. Consider the sup of the integral of the error multiplied by any bounded function $b; |b(x)| \leq 1$:
$$
\text{error} = \sup_{|b(x)| \leq 1} \int b(x) ( \hat\phi_n(x) - \phi(x) ) dx
$$

Show that this is equal to $Z$.
Show that is equal to twice the total variation distance.

In both cases, you find a particular $b$, yielding a lower-bound on the sup, then show an upper-bound.
Once you understand the argument for these two small exercises, it is of course fairly obvious to write a direct proof.

Thank you! For the first one, a $b$ that yields a lower bound is such that $b(x) = 1$ when the integrand in the L1 error is positive and $b(x) = -1$ when the integrand is negative. I also think you can show this is an upper bound. For this choice of $b$, it equals $Z$, thus $Z = error$.
For the second one, I got close to the answer by writing out the integral in the error term and using a similar $b$. This way, you can get the $P(A)$ term as $A$ is basically the borel set where $b(x) = 1$. However, I struggle with getting the empirical measure. Do you have any hints?

I don't understand your question. What empirical measure are you talking about? Every result we are discussing here holds for any two densities $p(x), q(x)$. the fact that one of them is a KDE computed on a dataset does not matter at all here. It'll matter in the rest of the analysis in which you will prove that $\hat \phi_n$ converges to $\phi$ using some glivenko-cantelli like result.
